# How to unmount webcam from Mac to make it work inside Virtualbox

Tags: macos, virtualbox

Unlike a USB pendrive, I am unable to select my webcam as a device for my virtual machine.

I get the following error when trying to do so:

```
Failed to attach the USB device Logitech Camera [0010] to the virtual machine Windows.
USB device 'Logitech Camera' with UUID {0fe606fc-298c-4250-aee3-f7fb6cc8ef2f} is busy with a previous request. Please try again later.
```

I get a similar error for a pendrive if it's mounted.

I am using VirtualBox with extension and guest additions installed.

How do I unmount my camera and make it work on my virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same error when i try to plug my old usb scanner into virtual box instance running windows XP. ( when i installed the drivers for the first time in virtual machine it worked. but after some time when i was trying to re plug it, error displayed "USB device is busy with a previous request")

what i did was

- i unplugged my scanner form USB port and unplug scanner from power
  source as well.
- then force closed the virtual machine without saving the status.
- Updated virtual box to the newest version.
- disable USB 2.0 (EHCI) support in BIOS, ( goto settings -> select USB devices)
- Start the virtual machine.
- Plugin the USB and then plug the scanner to the power source.
- Add a new filter to usb ( goto settings -> USB
  devices) then select the detected scanner from the bottom usb device
  list.

After doing so virtual box auto detected and  installed the drivers again

good luck